# XAMPP - Typing “localhost/my_site/” into URL not working

Tags: php, localhost, xampp

Using XAMPP installed on Mac OS X Mavericks, I've got the servers running and I use my Firefox Dev Edition to navigate to "localhost/my_site/".

Previously, I've been successful with other folders for websites I've created, but this time it's not working. Instead of interpreting the index.php and outputting HTML, it asks if I want to open or download the file.

I click open and it opens my PHP source file in my text editor. I've tried this in Google Chrome and Safari with same results.

Anybody else ever had this problem?

EDIT:
For whatever reason, I have overcome the problem by simply creating a new folder and moving the files into the new one. I deleted the "my_site" folder, renamed the new folder to "my_site" and the server is now properly interpreting the PHP again. Freak of nature I guess. Thanks for thinking about it anyway!

Comment: "other folders" within _localhost_? ie. within the same site/virtual host?

Comment: Like "localhost/myothersite/" and "localhost/anothersite/": those work. Just not "localhost/my_site/".

Comment: Is there anything different with the .htaccess file in this directory?

Comment: You might as well add your _edit_ as an answer - you can then accept it, so your question gets removed from the unanswered question queue. Just curious, was the new folder name exactly the same as the old folder name?

Comment: I have closed this because the problem went away for unknown reasons.

Comment: @w3d The folders were names exactly the same. Can't figure it out! It's working now...

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That's ok :-)